# Fastest way to query list of paginated api urls?

Tags: python, multithreading, api, request

I have a list of `api_urls`:

```
api_urls = [api_url_1, api_url_2, api_url_3]
```

For each of these URLs I have to loop through the pagination to get all the data:

```
def get_data(api_url):
    next_page = 1
    results = []
    while next_page is not None:
        response = query(api_url)
        results.extend(response["data"])
        next_page = response["next_page"]

    return results
```

What is the fastest way to get the data from all my `api_urls`? Can I do multithreading here?

Comment: `asyncio` is probably what you need here.

Comment: Multithreading would be a good iapproach since what you're doing is likely I/O-bound.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Threadpool to run the get_data function in 4 different threads in parallel.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

with ThreadPool(4) as pool:

    results = pool.map(get_data, api_urls)
```

This code executes the get_data functions with 4 threads in parallel until all api_urls are processed

You can also use this code to run the get_data function on 4 parallel processes using a normal multiprocessing pool

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

with Pool(4) as pool:

    results = pool.map(test, api_urls)
```